# Can an extended journal version consist of more than a conference paper?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, paper-submission, extended-paper

Can an extended version contains 2-3 conference papers? If yes, should all authors be listed or only the key contributors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extended journal version might well combine multiple input papers, though this is somewhat unusual.  In general if somebody was an author on one of the papers that is a source, then they should be an author on the composite.  The only exception that I can think of is if the resulting composite paper drops sections from some of the inputs, and certain authors had *only* been involved in those sections.  Again, this would seem to be a rather unusual situation, though plausible.